# Get event error in Jquery autocomplete remote datasource

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, error-handling, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Jquery autocomple with remote datasource, but, sometimes when try do search in my server a error is returned , because I'm using a rest webservice like datasource.
I'd like to know what returned status code by my webservice and print a error message
Example:

```
$(idObjeto).autocomplete({
            source:url,
            minLength: 3,
            select:function(data,ui){
                $(formatIdJQuery(idObjValueReceptor)).val(ui.item.id);
            }
        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + " - <strong>" + item.id + "</strong></a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
    }
```

Suppose what my webservice returned status code 404, I'd like to get this status code and call alert window, for example.

That's all folks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could re-structure your widget to use a function as the `source` parameter, then make the AJAX request yourself and do whatever you'd like upon an error:

```
$(idObjeto).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: request,
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]); // send no results to the widget.
                alert("an error occurred!");
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select:function(data,ui){
        $(formatIdJQuery(idObjValueReceptor)).val(ui.item.id);
    }
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + " - <strong>" + item.id + "</strong></a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
};
```